# Format decimal value as currency for specific language and currency

Tags: ios, swift, math, currency, number-formatting

I found out, that I could use the `NumberFormatter` by Swift to convert a decimal number to the almost correct output (seen from my point).

If I convert the number `10000.23` for the locale `en_US` then the output will be

```
$10,000.23
```

If I convert the same number with the locale `de_DE` then the output will be

```
10.000,23 €
```

My specific problem is, that the decimal divider is actually a comma (as seen for the second output) and the thousands divider is a dot. That means, that the dollar output is actually formatted wrong for the set system language (in my case german). Now my question is, how can I format the currency correctly (so the symbol is on the correct position // leading/trailing) and the number for a given language (system language) and a given currency ISO code.

**EDIT:**
The decimal places should also be taken into account. That means if a currency has normally 4 decimal places this should be concerned.

Comment: What is the correct position for the symbol here, always in the same place or? Actually the whole question is unclear, the decimal comma should always be formatted German style but all the rest should be what exactly? Maybe you can include how you expect some non German currencies should be formatted.

Comment: I have a currency and a language. I want to use the lange for the actual number formatting (decimal punctuation) and the currency for the symbol as well the placement of the symbol.

Comment: I don't think it's enough to have a currency and a language, you need a country as well.

Comment: Okay, that would not be a problem.